# Не понимаю как отсортировать строки по убыванию помогите

Tags: java

```
String name [] = {"So", "X", "Kort",};
    int sum [] = {name[0].length(),name[1].length(),name[2].length()};
    int a,b,t;
    int size = 3;
    for ( a = 1; a < 3; a++) {
        for ( b = size - 1; b >=a ; b--) {
            if (sum[ b - 1 ] > sum [b]){
                t = sum [b - 1];
                sum [b - 1] = sum [b];
                sum[b] = t;
            }

        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print(" "  + sum[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: https://www.techiedelight.com/sort-array-of-strings-java/

Comment: Спасибо большое